# How can I cache image files locally with PhoneGap / Cordova?

Tags: javascript, caching, cordova

Here's my problem :

I making a Web/Mobile app, using AngularJS and Cordova. For offline purpose, I use localStorage to store all the data of the app (JSON, parameters, and so on).

The thing is : I need to store / cache images locally (again, offline purpose). **As localStorage size limit is around 5mo, I can't use it, I need more**.

I thought I could use a cache manifest, but it doesn't work, as I need to update it regulary, without recompiling the app (I thought I could put the cache manifest on an external server, but it's like I can't use a cache manifest from another domain).

So I'm thinking of using Cordova/Phonegap File API, but **I have no idea to achieve that**...

Any help or ideas ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After long hours searching on SO and Github, I found **imgCache.js**, a JS library that handle file cache for Chrome, Android and iOs (through Cordova).

https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/

Then, basically :

```
var target = $('.cached-img');

ImgCache.isCached(target.attr('src'), function(path, success){
          if(success){
            // already cached
            ImgCache.useCachedFile(target);
          } else {
            // not there, need to cache the image
            ImgCache.cacheFile(target.attr('src'), function(){
              ImgCache.useCachedFile(target);
            });
          }
        });
```

Comment: How to do you define ImgCache in jquery?

Comment: See the readme on the Github page. On my example, target is a jQuery object (i.e. $('#myElement')) as I'm using attr() method.

Comment: what if you are building the target dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically" ? If it's server side, it's ok, if it's client-side, you have to wait the <img> element to be ready.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize the HTML5 FileSystem via the Cordova File plugin.  The Cordova File documentation should get you a FileEntry->File.  That File should then be usable via the HTML 5 FileSystem methods.  https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file